# How can I use variables with subscripts?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language, mathics

From [Mathics](https://mathics.org/),  I tried:

```
Subscript[a, 0] = 1
```

but it gives the error:

Tag Subscript in Subscript[a, 0] is Protected.

Comment: I am doing this in Mathics. It should be based on the same Wolfram language, that is why I added Mathematica in the tags. Mathics was mentioned in the title, but removed by a mod. Now I try to set it in the body.

Comment: @Bill: thank you, it could possibly be a bug on Mathics side. One alternative would be to use an array, e.g. `v =  Array[a, {3}]`, and applying an output format displaying the indices in `a[1], a[2] ...`  in subscripts. Is that possible for example in Mathematica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message means that what you are attempting to do doesn't make sense. Subscript is a system function that is protected from being inadvertently redefined, exactly as Plus (+) or any other built-in system function.

According to:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html

> Subscript is an object that formats as x_(y).

You get the same error message as if you tried:

```
 Plus[a, 0] = 1
```

Also note that lists in Wolfram Language and Mathics start at 1, not 0.

Here is how to create list variable *a* with an element containing the value 1 at index 1:

```
$ mathics

Mathics 2.0.1.dev
on CPython 3.8.8 (default, Feb 27 2021, 09:08:32) 
using SymPy 1.7.1, mpmath 1.2.1, numpy 1.20.1, cython 0.29.22

Copyright (C) 2011-2021 The Mathics Team.
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions.
See the documentation for the full license.

Quit by evaluating Quit[] or by pressing CONTROL-D.

In[1]:= a = {1}
Out[1]= {1}

In[2]:= a[[1]]
Out[2]= 1
```

Maybe https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/lists/ and https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/assignments/ are good places to start.

Comment: My interest in Wolfram language is also in its good-looking output. Is it possible to format a list (or an array) to be printed with a subscript style?

Comment: This seems like a totally different question. If this answer addresses this question accept it so as to help others. If it doesn't address the question, elaborate in the comments. 

As for the other question, probably https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask.

Comment: OK, I opened another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66912247/1851270).